# Script to find specific text inside <script> tag in HTML document

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to build a crawler that is made in JavaScript, but also uses node.js, plus the 'request', 'cheerio', and 'url-parse' node modules (installed using `npm`).

I would like to just find the second of a pair of scripts that contain the script tag `DM_redirect("http://mobile.` as the next node.

It looks like cheerio uses a stripped down version of jQuery and all of my attempts to find the correct command to target the second script with the text node have failed. Any input on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do it for you:

```
var match_count = 0;

$("script").text().each(function(index, value) {
    if (value.indexOf("DM_redirect(\"http://mobile.") {
        if (++match_count == 2) {
            // You've found the second instance.  Go ahead and process it...
        }
    }
});
```

Note that this will find the second occurrence across all script tags.  If you only want it to find the second within a given script tag, simply move the `var match_count = 0;` statement inside the `$.each` method, just before the first `if` statement.